# 403 Forbidden - cloud_storage_bucket get_media

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-storage

```
import json
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

json_file = 'my.json'
client_email = json.loads(open(json_file).read())['client_email']
private_key = json.loads(open(json_file).read())['private_key']

cloud_storage_bucket = 'my_bucket'
report_to_download = 'sales/salesreport_201907.zip'

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(client_email, private_key,['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control'])
storage = build('storage', 'v1', http=credentials.authorize(Http()))
object_metadata = storage.objects().get(bucket = cloud_storage_bucket, object = report_to_download).execute()
object_content = storage.objects().get_media(bucket = cloud_storage_bucket, object = report_to_download).execute()
```

I can read the object_metadata, but when requesting object content I get:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/my_bucket/o/sales%2Fsalesreport_201907.zip?alt=media returned "Forbidden">
```

As u can see I added the three scopes in the credentials sections just to ensure to have all the permissions. Despite that I still getting the error.

I am using Python 2.7.

**Edit:**

I tried to download the file using gsutil and it works. So it isn't related with permissions.

**Edit 2:**

Changed the code to use a non deprecated library.

```
from logs import logger
import google.auth
import google.auth.transport.requests as tr_requests
from google.resumable_media.requests import Download
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="my.json"

ro_scope=u'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control'
credentials,_ = google.auth.default(scopes=(ro_scope,))
transport = tr_requests.AuthorizedSession(credentials)

cloud_storage_bucket = 'pubsite_prod_rev_xxxx'
report_to_download = 'sales/salesreport_201907.zip'

#option 1
media_url='https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/pubsite_prod_rev_xxxx/o/sales%2Fsalesreport_201907.zip?generation=1234&alt=media'
#option 2
media_url='https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/pubsite_prod_rev_xxxx/o/sales%2Fsalesreport_201907.zip'

download = Download(media_url)
response = download.consume(transport)
print download.finished
```

When running the code with option 1 url the `status is 200` but the `response.content` is just the metadata, has happened before with the `get` method.

When running the option 2, like `get_media` method, the error stills `403`.

```
  File "/anaconda2/envs/enviro27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/resumable_media/_helpers.py", line 93, in require_status_code
    status_code, u'Expected one of', *status_codes)
google.resumable_media.common.InvalidResponse: (u'Request failed with status code', 403, u'Expected one of', 200, 206)
```

The [doc](https://googleapis.github.io/google-resumable-media-python/latest/google.resumable_media.requests.html) of this code.

Comment: Is your code is inside App Engine or another Google service? or is it in your local server?

Comment: It's in my local server. In this case, local computer.

Comment: I took a look at google Docs and found that as of 2016 SignedJwtAssertionCredentials class has been deprecated in the oauth2client library, the new suggested way is through ServiceAccountCredentials class, take a look to this [git issue](https://github.com/googleapis/oauth2client/issues/401) where they explain the change, please tell me if this solves it to write a proper answer.

Comment: Added an update to the question with the currens issue. It doesnt work, but at least provide some lights of when the code breaks.

Comment: 403 means forbidden access, but you also tried using gsutil, and succeed, what version of gsutils are you using, [see this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#libauth) and [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#authenticate)? did you logged into gsutils with the same service account? the service account has the correct [roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#storage-roles) assigned to it?

Comment: @Edgar-do Finally we found the issue. Seems like admin account was another email, and not the one displayed as contact information. Finally, we created a service account with the true admin account and we can connect to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution has been to discover the true admin account. 
Despite Google Play shows contact information to one email (the one that we believe to be the admin), the real admin is anothe account. After find it, we applied all the process explained [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?hl=en).

And with this code we are able to access the content:

```
from logs import logger
import google.auth
import google.auth.transport.requests as tr_requests
from google.resumable_media.requests import Download
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="my.json"

ro_scope=u'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control'
credentials,_ = google.auth.default(scopes=(ro_scope,))
transport = tr_requests.AuthorizedSession(credentials)

cloud_storage_bucket = 'pubsite_prod_rev_xxxx'
report_to_download = 'sales/salesreport_201907.zip'

#option 1
media_url='https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/pubsite_prod_rev_xxxx/o/sales%2Fsalesreport_201907.zip?generation=1234&alt=media'
#option 2
media_url='https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/pubsite_prod_rev_xxxx/o/sales%2Fsalesreport_201907.zip'

download = Download(media_url)
response = download.consume(transport)
print download.finished
```